# How to add data to Firebase without replacing using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send a time difference between two distances from my NodeJS server to Firebase database.

```
function sendDatabase(dbName, payload1) {
    var timeNow = getTime();
    console.log(timeNow);
    var ref = db.ref(dbName);
    ref.set({difference:payload1});
}
```

dBName = `IpBBEfCob0c1GaYkvAzog9rVdKn1/`

`payload1` is the time difference that I want to send.

`dbName` is a child node in the database and I want to save `payload1` as child node of `dbName` every single time it executes.

But every time this function executes it will just replace it and no new entry will be created. I know that this is because the property name `difference` is the same every time, therefore I searched on Google to see if I can make it unique so that it will not replace, but I could not find a proper answer to my issue.

I am a beginner to Firebase and help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `push()`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Comment: yes i tried push. But then it creates a unique ID node and saves just one instance under it. The next time it will create another node and save. What i want is to have everything in the same node

Comment: You want multiple instances of the same `difference` key?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want. but it shud be under the same dbName node

Comment: Instead, grab a reference to the `difference` node and `push()` children into it.  `push` is chronologically ordered, so the unique key nodes will appear in order and you can filter by `LimitToLast(2)` to grab the last 2 nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple instances of the same `key`.  Then it's not a `key` anymore.  You can't do this:

```
dbName
 - difference : 00
 - difference : 01
 - difference : 02
 - difference : ...
```

What you can do is have multiple children of difference:

```
dbName
  + difference
    - khghjgfvhgfh : 00
    - khghjgfvhgfi : 01
    - khghjgfvhgfj : 02
    - khghjgfvhgfk : ...
```

By [pushing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) unique children:

```
db.ref(dbName).child("difference").push(payload1)
```

`push` automatically orders children chronologically.

And when you query your nodes, [LimitToLast](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#filtering_data), First, etc...

```
db.ref(dbName).child("difference").limitToLast(2)
```